# How can I test a trigger function in GAS?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, triggers

Google Apps Script supports [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), that pass [Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) to trigger functions. Unfortunately, the development environment will let you test functions with no parameter passing, so you cannot simulate an event that way. If you try, you get an error like:

> ReferenceError: 'e' is not defined.

Or

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading '...')

(where `e` is undefined)

One could treat the event like an optional parameter, and insert a default value into the trigger function using any of the techniques from [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript). But that introduces a risk that a lazy programmer (hands up if that's you!) will leave that code behind, with unintended side effects.

Surely there are better ways?

Comment: Always look through all answers and find the latest update and NOT the accepted one only. Current(2020) update is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can write a test function that passes a simulated event to your trigger function. Here's an example that tests an `onEdit()` trigger function. It passes an event object with all the information described for "Spreadsheet Edit Events" in [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).

To use it, set your breakpoint in your target `onEdit` function, select function `test_onEdit` and hit `Debug`.

```js
/**
 * Test function for onEdit. Passes an event object to simulate an edit to
 * a cell in a spreadsheet.
 *
 * Check for updates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/1677912
 *
 * See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
 */
function test_onEdit() {
  onEdit({
    user : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
    source : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
    range : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell(),
    value : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getValue(),
    authMode : "LIMITED"
  });
}
```

If you're curious, this was written to test the `onEdit` function for [Google Spreadsheet conditional on three cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085461/google-spreadsheet-conditional-on-three-cells).

Here's a test function for Spreadsheet Form Submission events. It builds its simulated event by reading form submission data. This was originally written for [Getting TypeError in onFormSubmit trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984230/how-do-i-fix-typeerror-when-trying-to-merge-google-form-data-to-pdf-and-send-to/17984695#17984695).

```js
/**
 * Test function for Spreadsheet Form Submit trigger functions.
 * Loops through content of sheet, creating simulated Form Submit Events.
 *
 * Check for updates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/1677912
 *
 * See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
 */
function test_onFormSubmit() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  // Start at row 1, skipping headers in row 0
  for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row].filter(Boolean);  // filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19888749
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
    e.namedValues = {};
    // Loop through headers to create namedValues object
    // NOTE: all namedValues are arrays.
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = [data[row][col]];
    }
    // Pass the simulated event to onFormSubmit
    onFormSubmit(e);
  }
}
```

#### Tips

When simulating events, take care to match the documented event objects as close as possible.

- If you wish to validate the documentation, you can log the received event from your trigger function.

  ```js
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify( e , null, 2 ) );
  ```
- In Spreadsheet form submission events:

  - all namedValues values are arrays.
  - Timestamps are Strings, and their format will be localized to the Form's locale. If read from a spreadsheet with default formatting<sup>*</sup>, they are Date objects. If your trigger function relies on the string format of the timestamp (which is a Bad Idea), take care to ensure you simulate the value appropriately.
  - If you've got columns in your spreadsheet that are not in your form, the technique in this script will simulate an "event" with those additional values included, which is not what you'll receive from a form submission.
  - As reported in [Issue 4335](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4355), the `values` array skips over blank answers (in "new Forms" + "new Sheets"). The `filter(Boolean)` method is used to simulate this behavior.

---

<sup>*</sup>A cell formatted "plain text" will preserve the date as a string, and is not a Good Idea.

Comment: @Mogsdad : thanks for noticing the array thing... I updated my script(s) accordingly ;-) btw, I forgot to mention I took the idea from you but this post is such a 'hit' anyway that it won't change your life isn't it XD sorry about that , omission repaired ;-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas - I'd swear that those values weren't always arrays, maybe they changed with new Sheets? Or perhaps I was using them in ways that worked for arrays, e.g. indexOf() searches. Anyway, better to get it right.

Comment: The form submission simulation I used was working perfectly without arrays... it still works with it without noticeable differences. I examined another script where I wrote the Logger result of a real form and didn't see the array brackets so there are 2 possibilities : 1 I wasn't wearing my glasses - 2 there was no brackets... I can't be sure which one is true ;-)

Comment: Erratum : I found an log written in december 2013 that is as follows : `« /* {"namedValues":{"user name":["test name"],"a comment":["gxfgxdfhdgfhjfgjhfgjxfgj"],"Timestamp":["1/2/2014 22:17:24"]},"values":["1/2/2014 22:17:24","test name","gxfgxdfhdgfhjfgjhfgjxfgj"],"source":{},"range":{"rowStart":2,"rowEnd":2,"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":1}}
*/   »` the brackets are there !!! so it's not so new...

Extrait de: « Google Apps Script for Beginners [eBook].epub. » iBooks.

Comment: test_onEdit, when run/debug from GScript IDE, gives an error of: "Please select an active sheet first".  I've tried opening a spreadsheet and setting an active sheet within test_onEdit, but the same error stops execution right as onEdit is called.

Am I missing a preliminary step?

Comment: brilliant, would have never thought just to cheat like this!

Comment: JSON.stringify(e) = AWESOME!

Answer (score 17):

#### Update 2020-2021:

You don't need to use any kind of mocks events as suggested in the previous answers.

As said in the question, If you directly "run" the function in the script editor, Errors like

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'range')

are thrown. These are not the real errors. This error is only because you ran the function without a event. If your function isn't behaving as expected, You need to figure out the actual error:

To test a trigger function,

1. Trigger the corresponding event manually: i.e., To test `onEdit`, edit a cell in sheet; To test `onFormSubmit`, submit a dummy form response; To test `doGet`,  navigate your browser to the published webapp `/exec` url.
2. If there are any errors, it is logged  to stackdriver. To view those logs,

   - In Script editor > Execution icon on the left bar(**Legacy editor:** View > Executions).
   - Alternatively, Click [here](https://script.google.com/home) > Click the project you're interested in >   Click "Executions" icon on the left bar(the 4th one)
3. You'll find a list of executions in the executions page. Make sure to clear out any filters like "Ran as:Me" on the top left to show all executions. Click the execution you're interested in, it'll show the error that caused the trigger to fail in red.

> Note: Sometimes, The logs are not visible due to bugs. This is true especially in case of webapp being run by anonymous users. In such cases, It is recommended to Switch Default Google cloud project  to a standard Google cloud  project and use View> Stackdriver logging directly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002160/) for more  information.

4. For further debugging, You can use  edit the code to add `console.log(/*object you're interested in*/)` after any line you're interested in to see  details of that object. It is **highly recommended** that you stringify the object you're looking for: `console.log(JSON.stringify(e))` as the log viewer has idiosyncrasies. After adding `console.log()`, repeat from Step 1. Repeat this cycle until you've narrowed down the problem.

Congrats! You've successfully figured out the problem and crossed the first obstacle.

Comment: This solution won't fit add-on development testing, but it's more of add-on development issue itself.

Answer (score 10):

**2017 Update:**
Debug the [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) with [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) for Google Apps Script. From the menu bar in the script editor, goto:
`View > Stackdriver Logging` to view  or stream the logs.

[console.log()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) will write `DEBUG` level messages

Example **onEdit()**:

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var debug_e = {
    authMode:  e.authMode,  
    range:  e.range.getA1Notation(),    
    source:  e.source.getId(),
    user:  e.user,   
    value:  e.value,
    oldValue: e. oldValue
  }

  console.log({message: 'onEdit() Event Object', eventObject: debug_e});
}
```

Example **onFormSubmit()**:

```
function onFormSubmit (e) {
  var debug_e = {
    authMode:  e.authMode,  
    namedValues: e.namedValues,
    range:  e.range.getA1Notation(),
    value:  e.value
  }

  console.log({message: 'onFormSubmit() Event Object', eventObject: debug_e});
}
```

Example **onChange()**:

```
function onChange (e) {
  var debug_e = {
    authMode:  e.authMode,  
    changeType: changeType,
    user:  e.user
  }

  console.log({message: 'onChange() Event Object', eventObject: debug_e});
}
```

Then check the logs in the [Stackdriver UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) labeled as the `message` string to see the output

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the method mentioned above (**Update 2020**) in point 4.:
Here is a small routine which I use to trace triggered code and that has saved me a lot of time already. Also I have two windows open: One with the stackdriver (executions), and one with the code (which mostly resides in a library), so I can easily spot the culprit.

```js
/**
 *
 * like Logger.log %s in text is replaced by subsequent (stringified) elements in array A
 * @param {string | object} text %s in text is replaced by elements of A[], if text is not a string, it is stringified and A is ignored
 * @param {object[]} A array of objects to insert in text, replaces %s
 * @returns {string} text with objects from A inserted 
 */
function Stringify(text, A) {
  var i = 0 ;
  return (typeof text == 'string') ? 
      text.replace(
        /%s/g, 
        function(m) { 
          if( i >= A.length) return m ;
          var a = A[i++] ;
          return (typeof a == 'string') ? a :  JSON.stringify(a) ;
        } ) 
      : (typeof text == 'object') ? JSON.stringify(text) : text ;
}

/* use Logger (or console) to display text and variables. */
function T(text) {
  Logger.log.apply(Logger, arguments) ;
  var Content = Stringify( text, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1) ) ;
  return Content ;
}

/**** EXAMPLE OF USE ***/
function onSubmitForm(e) {
  T("responses:\n%s" , e.response.getItemResponses().map(r => r.getResponse()) ;
}
```